# rosserial_arduino helloworld program is not working (ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tutorial page : http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World

Hello I install the necessary requirements for rosserial_arduino and imported the examples in arduino File -> Examples -> roslib

while compiling I got the following error message

/usr/share/arduino/libraries/ros_lib/ArduinoHardware.h:38:22: fatal error: WProgram.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

what may be the error ?
I'm uses Ubuntu 12.10

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57233/rosserial_arduino-helloworld-program-is-not-working-(ubuntu-12.10)/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey me to find out the solution

just need to replace the WProgram.h in the file ArduinoHardware.h to Arduino.h

---

Originally posted by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) with karma: 313 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2